# How to run Ruby on Rails app on Ubuntu 18.04 with Terminal Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-18.04, rubymine

I have Ruby on Rails app that download on Github. I use Ubuntu 18.04 and RubyMine tool.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let do command in RM terminal or system's terminal.

```
~$ bundle intall
....
~$ rake db:migrate
~$ rake db:seed
...
~$ rails s
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it as your method.
But there are issues.....

fullstack@fullstack-SVF152100C:~/git_environment/Braaam$ bundle install
Your Gemfile lists the gem active_storage_validations (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

let try below commands.

```
~$ rvm list
```

if there is ruby-2.5.3

```
~$ /bin/bash --login
~$ rvm use 2.5.3
```

and then let try again before commands.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitriy. it is running now...

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, It is not good to answer multiple time, please read [Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and merge your answer in order to give a valuable answer in one answer.